# how to search array elements in mongodb against fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have any array coming from user wit ingredients in it. I have two collection name one is recipe collection where i stored recipes with ingredients name. so I am able to search that array in recipe collection. But I have another collection name Nutrition where I have nutrition food or you can say ingredient so I have to search name of the ingredient from the nutrition collection which are same a coming req array. like my coming array is ['salmon','fish','almonds'] so I have to search there array elements in mu nutrition collection and my nutrition collection is like

```
{"name":"Egg","protein:6,"carbs":8,"calorie":72}
```

so I have to compare array elements with name fields

[image]

Comment: Hi Ashish, You have explained here what you are doing but can you please explain what is the exact issue that you are facing? If possible can you please share data from recipe and nutrition collection so we can try our solution?

Comment: I solved my query thanks. but I have one more question. Does my 13th line const getmeals=req.body.getmeals is correct? in GET http verb??? although its working fine

Comment: No, It is not a good practice to get data in req body in GET API. You can pass it in query params or use POST API to send data in req body.

Comment: if I use POST method to req body then How can I use data from  body data into GET verb and do manipulation. like in my code I receive an array from the user and to search that array into my database along with queries I get from GET URL